Calling my API from .NET MAUI app using MSAL
I'm implementing MSAL in my ASP.NET Core Web API and .NET MAUI apps to authenticate users against Azure AD B2C.
I'm following this code sample to implement this on the .NET MAUI app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-dotnet-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-dotnet-tutorial-2-sign-in-maui/
As I understand it from the "Best Practices" section, I don't handle things like token acquisition or refresh tokens manually and let MSAL handle them for me.
I'm just not clear about how to make GET and POST calls to my API. When I handled the process manually, I'd add the access_token into my Http call header as Bearer. How do I handle this with MSAL? I suspect there's some helper method in the code but I'm not seeing it yet and I'd appreciate some pointers here.

This is probably a better sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-maui?tab=readme-ov-file

With MSAL you can request to silent token acquisition, then add this token to your api calls
